# resetting Arduino from matlab

Tags: arduino, matlab

I'm using serial communication with Arduino and Matlab, and I need a way to reset Arduno from Matlab once a serial connection is made. I'm using Leonardo, and I understand that it uses a virtual serial interface unlike other boards. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect an IO pin to RESET pin via suitable resistor usually 1kR, then trigger IO pin to achieve reset in case you won't find any reset command in library

Comment: so, do I send a command to the IO pin or will it automatically restart when the serial connection is established?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and Arduino was stuck in a resetting loop, even though I put an if statement to check for the incoming command from the serial port and only set pin 7 to HIGH when a certain char is received.

Comment: This is that IO got latched, Try reversing polarity of reset IO or use external watchdog chip.

Comment: Yes, I've set it as the following  pinMode(6, INPUT);     digitalWrite(6, LOW);  in void setup, then pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW); in void loop and it works fine now. Thanks,